# How do I capture logs with colour formatters in python behave?

Tags: python, logging, python-behave, ansi-colors

I would like to have coloured output in `logging` captured by `python behave` and print it in case of test failures. For example, this  logging captured by `pytest`:

[image]

While a similar test on `behave` produce logs in this format:

[image]

I tried using the `coloredlogs` framework but it completely prevented log capturing and logs were printed to `stdout` no matter if a test failed or not. Is there an alternative method/framework that works with `behave`?